# qt creator (3.5.1) crashes at opening source code

Tags: qt5

I tried to compile one example from CGAL 
(link: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html) 
on Qt5.5.1, which is installed on windows10 64bit. the installed CGAL version is 4.11.
problem is: I can qmake ,build and even run the project perfectly. But whenever I opened the source code, Qtcreator crahed without any error message. I find out that this would not happen again when I do not include the cgal header file `<surface_mesh_default_triangulation.h>` in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on SO!

Version 3.5.1 of Qt Creator is quite old (> 3 years now). Maybe you are experiencing a bug with the code model plugin...

I would suggest to upgrade to the latest Qt Creator (4.6.2), you can find the installers [here](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/4.6/4.6.2/).